# Where did this coin come from?

Tags: united-states

This coin has been in our family for over 70 years. I have seen hundreds of these coins on line but, I have never seen one like this. Do you have any thoughts on where this coin may have come from?
Thank you ...
Tony
[image: coin with world Columbia exposition legend]

Comment: I googled for the words in the legend and found a few sources. Let us know if [coinweek](https://coinweek.com/coins/commemoratives-coin-guide/1892-1893-columbian-exposition-half-dollar/) is helpful.  The coin in top left  has a different border than bottom left - looks like the top coin is mounted in something. This would support @Schwern's inferences below.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to History.SE. Are all these pictures of the same coin? If so, is the toothed edge a case that can be removed?

Answer (score 15):

It's a [US Columbian Half Dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbian_half_dollar) minted to sponsor the [*World's Colombian Exposition* held in Chicago in 1893](https://www.bie-paris.org/site/en/1893-chicago) aka [*Chicago World's Fair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_Columbian_Exposition). It appears someone has painted the reverse side and put it in a custom case.

[image]

[Painting coins](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=painting+coins&t=ffsb&ia=web) is something I did not realize is a thing. I can't say who painted your coin, but perhaps you can contact some enthusiasts.

Comment: That painting is a really good job, considering the size of the coin. I tried my hand at painting models (with details far larger than on that coin) as a kid, and was hopeless at it. And that was when I was young and my eyes were good.

Comment: I thought it was officially colored that way until this answer. Now the 1942 kinda stands out, but definitely superb work.

Comment: I wonder if the *coin painting* might have been a booth at the fair? That would explain the high quality.